# How to implement pop-up behavior in Looker table cells on click?

Tags: visualization, looker-studio

I'm working with Looker and have a table displaying product information, including product SKUs.I'd like to implement a feature where clicking on a product SKU in the table opens a pop-up or additional information related to that SKU , for exemple colors and when I click the color the related sizes to that color shows up.

I've already set up dependent filters for product SKU, color, and size, and the table is configured accordingly. However, I'm looking for a way to make the user experience more interactive by having a pop-up appear when a user clicks on a specific product SKU in the table.

Is there a built-in feature, plugin, or method within Looker to achieve this and if not then can someone provide out of the box guidance on how to implement this behavior in Looker studio?

Thanks in advance for any insights or suggestions!

I have searched alot on this but found no solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.